# How can I change the password used to connect to MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

How can I change the password value that is used in new mysqli($servername $username $password $dbname)? I already changed it in my phpMyAdmin account, but if I put my new password replacing the "$password" variable it doesn't work

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: If the account is correct and the command was accepted, perhaps you did not issue a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` command? Shouldn't matter, but who knows.

Comment: @Dharman I don't know exactly where the password that I should use in "$password" comes from. I thought that it was supposed to be the one in phpMyAdmin, so I tried to create a new password in phpMyAdmin. The new password failed, but the old one that I used in phpMyAdmin worked.

Comment: MySQL users also have another scope, you can define different passwords for the same user by using a different hostname.

Comment: You can use phpMyAdmin to change the MySQL password. I don't know if you use the same credentials to log in to MySQL via mysqli and phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way to change passwords in MySQL is like this:

```
ALTER USER username@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `username@'%'` with a proper user name, and `superSecretPassword!123` with a proper password.</sup>

However, you can also use `SET PASSWORD`:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'%' = 'superSecretPassword!123';
```

If it's just *your* account that you're updating, then you do not need to specify the account:

```
SET PASSWORD = 'superSecretPassword!123';
```

You can learn more about assigning passwords [from the documentation on MySQL's website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/assigning-passwords.html)